# Fabric js Itext box sizing issue with custom fonts

Tags: fonts, size, fabricjs

I have an issue with fabircjs IText box sizing for custom fonts.

- Goldsaber
- Earwig Factory

When I choose one of above mentioned fonts the text box size is bigger then default text "Vloz Text"(there is space at the end of the text and box border), but for some standart font, for example "Arial" text feets to the text-box(there isn't mentioned space). Also in case of "Goldsaber" text-box size gets bigger and bigger than text itself (mentioned space gets bigger).
I want it to behave the same way as Arial. It means text-size should always feet text-box without any space between the last character of text and text-box border.

```
javascript:

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

addText("Vlož Text", "Arial", 50, 50);
addText("Vlož Tssssssssssssssssext", "Arial", 50, 250);
addText("Vlož Text", "Goldsaber", 100, 50);
addText("Vlož Tssssssssssssssssext", "Goldsaber", 100, 250);
addText("Vlož Text", "Earwig factory", 150, 50);
addText("Vlož Tssssssssssssssssext", "Earwig Factory", 150, 250);

function addText(text, font, top, left) {
  var text = new fabric.IText(text, {
  fontFamily: font,
  fontSize: 25,
  top: top,
  left: left,
  originY: 'top',
  originX: 'left',
  padding: 0,
  lineHeight: 0.9,
  transparentCorners: false
});

canvas.add(text);
}

html:
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/13zgk2fs/12/

To see the problem please install also above mentioned fonts locally. I had problems to set-up custom fonts in jsfiddle.

Comment: I removed the iText tag. Please check the description of the iText tag. You will notice that iText® is something completely different than what you are using. (iText is a registered trademark; third parties really shouldn't use it. They should rename whatever they use the name iText for to avoid confusion.)

Comment: Yes, I saw. I have tried to find fabricjs related Itext tag, but seems there isn't. So I'll left as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look this https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3588 . If i correctly understood - it is same problem

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. Thanks, I'll have a look.